# Angular 6 Server side rendering with angular universal gives error Zone is not defined

Tags: angular, angular6, server-side-rendering

I have setup project and that works completely fine with ng serve.

I want to make it to server side redering so i have added @ng-toolkit/universal by ng add @ng-toolkit/universal and it is added.

steps are as follows :

```
step 1 : ng add @ng-toolkit/universal
step 2 : npm run build:prod
step 3 : npm run server
```

step 1 will add the server side rendering code structure automatically then step 2 will create build of an application till that works fine now when I do step 3 at that time get ReferenceError: Zone is not defined

```
/var/www/html/myproject/dist/server.js:220102
Zone.__load_patch('ZoneAwarePromise', function (global, Zone, api) {
^
ReferenceError: Zone is not defined
at /var/www/html/myproject/dist/server.js:220102:1
at module.exports.FUNCTION (/var/www/html/myproject/dist/server.js:219466:10)
at Object.module.exports.Object.defineProperty.value (/var/www/html/myproject/dist/server.js:219468:2)
at __webpack_require__ (/var/www/html/myproject/dist/server.js:21:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/myproject/dist/server.js:221764:1)
at __webpack_require__ (/var/www/html/myproject/dist/server.js:21:30)
at /var/www/html/myproject/dist/server.js:70:18
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/myproject/dist/server.js:73:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myproject@0.0.0 server: `node local.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the myproject@0.0.0 server script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/nitin/.npm/_logs/2018-07-26T05_47_07_681Z-debug.log
```

I have checked my polyfills.ts it contais the  import 'zone.js/dist/zone';

I tried by commenting in polyfills.ts and then added following code in main.ts then follows the steps but in step 3 get same error.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, {
ngZone: 'noop'
)
.catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

Comment: check this links https://github.com/angular/zone.js/issues/776

Comment: I have followed that link but not work for me

Comment: Have you added dependency for zone in package.json? like `"zone.js": "^0.8.26"`

Answer (score 0):

Add dependency for Zone like -

`"zone.js": "^0.8.26"`

Comment: Hi, I have exactly same problem with Angular SSR and it doesn't work on my side. I already added "zone.js" in my package.json.